# jdbc SQL statements receive data in java program

Tags: java

```
String sql2="SELECT rates from room_type a,rooms b ,reservation r where a.type=b.type AND b.room_no=r.room_no AND r.cus_id='"+Cusid+"' group by r.cus_id";
pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql2);
rs=pst.executeQuery();
rs.next();
double roomRates = Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("rates"));
```

I have used rs.next() without if statement. Is this correct? My program gets stuck when I run it. I suspect the reason is using rs.next() without "if".

Comment: Are you sure your RS will ALWAYS contain at least a row? You should check if there is a row to be read before trying to read data.

Comment: The `if` or `while` is not the reason, but it is very useful to determine if there were any rows returned or when you reached the end. If there should be a line but isn't you can throw an exception or take other steps to resolve it.

Comment: `Double.parseDouble(rs.getString("rates"));` should be replaced with `rs.getDouble("rates")` it makes not sense to convert a number to a string just to convert  it back to a number

Answer (score 0):

Please do yourself a favor, read the result set with a while loop or at least a conditional if even if your are 99,9% sure that there will always be one row returned:

```
double roomRates = 0.0;
if(!rs.next()){
    //handle no result
} else {
   roomRates = rs.getDouble("rates") != null ? rs.getDouble("rates") : 0.0;
}
```